# DropDownList with DataValueField and DataTextField asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

In my database, I entry CPVComID value from DropDownList (like
0,1,2,3)  and display dataValueFiled value into DropDownList like
(-Select-, Conquest, CBC, Insight Management).

**Error Message:**

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'ddlCardCPVComName' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because itdoes not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCardCPVComName" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
DataSourceID="SqlDSCPVCompanyName" DataTextField="CPVComName" 
dataValueFiled="ddlCardCPVComName" Width="205px" DataValueField="CPVComID">
<asp:ListItem Value="0"> -SELECT- </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSCPVCompanyName" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>"  
SelectCommand="SELECT CPVComID, CPVComName FROM DDCPVCompanyName ORDER BY CPVComID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
  private void getReceeivedCPV()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string str = @"SELECT CardCPVID, CardID, 
        CardCPVComName, 
        CardCPVSentDate, CardCPVStatus, CardCPVRcevDate, CPVRemarks  FROM CC_CardCPV Where CardID LIKE '" + GVCPVReceived.SelectedValue + "'";
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {

                            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
                            ddlCardCPVComName.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
                            txtCardCPVSentDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3]).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                            ddlCardCPVStatus.SelectedItem.Value = Convert.ToString(dr[4]);
                            if (dr[5] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                txtCardCPVRcevDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[5]).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                txtCardCPVRcevDate.Text = "";
                            }
                            txtCPVRemarks.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[6]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

What should I do? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I can describe why this exception arises..In the below line of code you are setting a value to the dropdownlist **ddlCardCPVComName**..

```
ddlCardCPVComName.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
```

Here the exception says that there is no such an item in the dropdownlist **ddlCardCPVComName**.So you must check when you bind the dropdownlist **ddlCardCPVComName**
that there exist the particular item which you are going to set..

Check this binding query and make sure that the desired items are bound to the datasource..

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSCPVCompanyName" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon %>"  
SelectCommand="SELECT CPVComID, CPVComName FROM DDCPVCompanyName ORDER BY CPVComID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, Remove dataValueFiled="ddlCardCPVComName"(DropDown) from Your aspx code and execute.

Answer (score 0):

I just change "dlCardCPVStatus.SelectedItem.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[4]);" and success to do this